# Jpa Transaction for update is throwing exception for the 2nd update

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am updating the row in the database using spring `Propagation.REQUIRED`, it is updating fine first time, but throwing exception second time.

```
03:44:58,206 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/wad].[springMain]] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servle
t springMain threw exception: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect
): [com.guthyrenker.wad.core.model.lookup.PublisherLookupItem#4025]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:492) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Fin
al]
```

Code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/updatePublisher.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody
JsonDataWrapper<PublisherLookupItem> updatePublisher(@RequestBody("PublisherLookupItem") publisherLookupItem, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

    wadRepository.updatePublisher(publisherLookupItem);
    JsonDataWrapper<PublisherLookupItem> result = new JsonDataWrapper<PublisherLookupItem>(publishertList);
    return result;
}

package com.wad.service
public interface WadRepository
{
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public PublisherLookupItem updatePublisher(PublisherLookupItem publisherLookupItem);
}

package com.wad.service.impl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.wad.core.dao.WadDAO;
import com.wad.core.model.lookup.PublisherLookupItem;
import com.wad.core.service.ServiceException;
import com.wad.core.service.WadRepository;

@Repository
public class WadRepositoryImpl implements WadRepository
{
    @Autowired
    private WadDAO wadDAO;

    @Override
    public PublisherLookupItem updatePublisher(PublisherLookupItem publisherLookupItem) {
        return wadDAO.savePublishers(publisherLookupItem);
    }
}

@Repository
public class WadDAO
{   
    public PublisherLookupItem savePublishers(PublisherLookupItem publisherLookupItem) {
        publisherLookupItem = em.merge(publisherLookupItem);
        return publisherLookupItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.) is a typo?

Comment: Yes, it was typo, actual value is @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED), will update the code.

Answer (score 0):

In you controller annotated with `@RequestMapping`, you need to put the instance returned by `wadRepository.updatePublisher(...)` in your `JsonDataWrapper<PublisherLookupItem> result`.

From your code, right now you are returning the stale instance of `PublisherLookupItem` in the response hence the stale object exception next time you try to merge that instance.